# Curl - can't get the content of a page and/or post data on that page

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get a webpage using `curl` but i get only a blank page, no output. Here is how i'm trying to do it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/b2b/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 " );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

After some research i tried to add this like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Encoding: gzip'));
```

And also this is how i'm trying to echo it out after adding the last line:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$content = @gzdecode($response);
echo ($content !== false) ? $content : $response;
```

Am i doing something wrong? I mean this works if i change the url with another website's url :(.

P.S This is what i get if i `print_r` `curl_getinfo()`:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://example.com/b2b/
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What should the page you are requesting return?

Comment: Hey @TomUdding, that page should return a login form(later i want to post some fields to log in using curl - i've already tried to log in but i get the same blank page :( )

Comment: Have you tried removing all the gzip related code and just using `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');`?

Comment: @TomUdding i tried it now, still didn't work - can i share the url with you so you can take a look?pleeeeeeese :-s

Comment: Yeah sure. Just to make sure, you want the whole page, right? The HTML part of it, to (probably) get the name attributes of the inputs inside the form.

Comment: Very strange this, I can get it to work without using PHP. But when trying it in PHP it will straight up fail. I'll check if I can think of something to fix it.

Comment: See my answer for the explanation on why it won't work.

Comment: Oky @TomUdding :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a more technical than practical answer but I'll explain what is happening here and why the requested webpage cannot be fetched by cURL.

*Please note that this seems to be an edge case. It might work on your system while it does not work on other systems. See [Symantec PKI Distrust](https://security.googleblog.com/2018/03/distrust-of-symantec-pki-immediate.html) for more information.*

---

**What is happening?**
To see what is happing when making the cURL call one should enable `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` logging:

```
* Hostname [REDACTED] was found in DNS cache
*   Trying [REDACTED]...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to [REDACTED] ([REDACTED]) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
```

From this we can conclude that the certificate used to issue the TLS certificate of the website cannot be found in the CA truststore of cURL (located in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` on this system).

Now one might wonder why this is the case. Well that is because of [the distrust of the CA certificate](https://security.googleblog.com/2018/03/distrust-of-symantec-pki-immediate.html) that issues the certificate for this website. The website uses a RapidSSL TLS certificate, which is issued before the 1st of December 2017. This means it falls withing the distrust section of old RapidSSL certificates.

---

**How can this be solved?**
Well you cannot really do anything. It is up to the owner of the website to update their TLS certificates. They should really be doing this because Chrome will start throwing nasty errors real soon. (Errors should already be appearing in the M70 beta versions. After the 16th of October all releases [>M70] will throw big nasty errors.)

Except that you can bypass the SSL/TLS certificate checks in cURL.
***I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS, YOU SHOULD NEVER DISABLE THE CERTIFICATE CHECKS!***
You can use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

to disable the checks and after that cURL will return the webpage:

```
<?php
$url = "https://[REDACTED]";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // one should never do this
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // or this!!!
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
// all kinds of HTML and other things
?>
```

---

**Conclusion**
The requested website uses a certificate that will be distrusted/is already distrusted and therefore cURL cannot complete the TLS handshake to establish a secure connection to the website. This is all due to the [Distrust of the Symantec PKI](https://security.googleblog.com/2018/03/distrust-of-symantec-pki-immediate.html).

*Please note (again) that one should never disable the security checks.*

Comment: Tommmmm you saved my life <3 :D this works, perfectly <3 Buuuut one question: why one shouldn't choose to not verify the ssl

Comment: @emma The certificates are there for a reason. They make sure that everything you send and receive is encrypted, it prevents so called "Man in The Middle"-attacks. In such an attack a malicious party might modify the content before you receive it. Troy Hunt (and Scott Helma) has a few very good write-ups on this topic. I suggest you read https://www.troyhunt.com/heres-why-your-static-website-needs-https/ for more information.